# How to store values in a veriable and get the value on change function?

Tags: jquery, variables, global-variables

I have a list of variables which stores different values, I'm using these variables to check for multiple change functions, currently, I have to declare the variable every time I want to check for a change. How can I declare them once and then access their value on multiple change functions.

```js
jQuery('#fontWeight').on('change', function() {
 var getFontweight = jQuery('#fontWeight').val();
 jQuery(".preview").css('font-weight', getFontweight);
});
jQuery('#fontTransform').on('change', function() {
 var getFonttransform = jQuery('#fontTransform').val();
 jQuery(".preview").css('text-transform', getFonttransform);
});
jQuery('#fontWeight, #fontTransform').on('change', function() {
 var getFontweight = jQuery('#fontWeight').val();
 var getFonttransform = jQuery('#fontTransform').val();
 document.getElementById('g-code').innerHTML =
        '#text{\n'+
  '    font-weight: '+getFontweight+';\n'+
  '    text-transform: '+getFonttransform+';\n'+
        '}';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="font-weight" id="fontWeight">
  <option value="normal">Normal</option>
  <option value="bold">Bold</option>
</select>
<select class="font-transform" id="fontTransform">
  <option value="none">Normal</option>
  <option value="uppercase">Uppercase</option>
  <option value="lowercase">Lowercase</option>
</select>
<div class="preview">Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack. </div>
<textarea id="g-code" onFocus="this.select()" onClick="this.focus();this.select()" readonly='readonly'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is moot as you don't need multiple `change` event handlers. Combine them all in to one:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#fontWeight, #fontTransform').on('change', function() {
    var fontWeight = $('#fontWeight').val();
    var fontTransform = $('#fontTransform').val();

    $(".preview").css({
      'font-weight': fontWeight,
      'text-transform': fontTransform
    });

    $('#g-code').html(`#text {\n  font-weight: ${fontWeight};\n  text-transform: ${fontTransform};\n}`);
  }).trigger('change');
  
  $('#g-code').on('focus click', e => e.target.select()); 
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="font-weight" id="fontWeight">
  <option value="normal">Normal</option>
  <option value="bold">Bold</option>
</select>
<select class="font-transform" id="fontTransform">
  <option value="none">Normal</option>
  <option value="uppercase">Uppercase</option>
  <option value="lowercase">Lowercase</option>
</select>

<div class="preview">Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen and Jack. </div>
<textarea id="g-code" readonly="true"></textarea>
```